# How do I match a string to a regex using Lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm unable to successfully match a string to a regex using Lodash.

I've would attempt the following code example:

```
regex = /foo/;

// ele.id might be undefined
_.result(ele.id, 'match(regex)');
_.invoke(ele.id, ['match'], [regex]);
_.invoke(ele.id, ['match'], ['regex']);
```

Does anyone know how to string match a regex argument using Lodash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_.invoke` is the correct function to use, but your syntax is slightly wrong. Take a look at [the docs](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#invoke): The *arguments to invoke the method with* (3rd parameter of `invoke`) are not in an array, and in your case the `path` argument (2nd parameter of `invoke`) is a simple string, too. This is how to do it:

```
// A string
let string = "foo";

// A matching regex (not the case in the original post)
let regex = /foo/;

// Does it match? Note there's two pairs of [] 
// that shouldn't be there in the original post.
let result = _.invoke(string, "match", regex);

// ["foo"]
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use vanilla JS for this?

```js
    var regex = /foo/;
    var string = "foo";
    
    console.log(regex.test(string))
```

Comment: I modified my original post to give better context on why I would use Lodash.

Answer (score 0):

you can just do it in plain Javascript. Try

```
const regex = /foo/;
const testString = "bar";
if(regex.test(testString)) {
   // code..
}
```